# Download function failing with file size 1.35gb

Tags: c#, .net, download

I have this download function, and it's working great. BUT with a file with filesize of 1.35gb the download stops at 300 Mb, 382, 400mb or 1.27 Gb. What am I doing wrong? *(The download function is made this way, because files need to be hidden, and may not be published on the website.)*

```
public static void downloadFunction(string filename)
{
    string filepath = @"D:\texts\New folder\DLfolder\" + filename;
    string contentType = "application/x-newton-compatible-pkg";

    Stream iStream = null;
    // Buffer to read 10K bytes in chunk
    //byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];
    // Buffer to read 1024K bytes in chunk

    byte[] buffer = new Byte[1048576];

    // Length of the file:
    int length;

    // Total bytes to read:
    long dataToRead;

    try
    {
        // Open the file.
        iStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

        // Total bytes to read:
        dataToRead = iStream.Length;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = contentType;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filename, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", iStream.Length.ToString());

        // Read the bytes.
        while (dataToRead > 0)
        {
            // Verify that the client is connected.
            if (HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                // Read the data in buffer.
                length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);

                // Write the data to the current output stream.
                HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

                buffer = new Byte[10000];
                dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
            }
            else
            {
                // Prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                dataToRead = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Trap the error, if any.
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message + "<br />");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Error : file not found");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (iStream != null)
        {
            //Close the file.
            iStream.Close();
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error-messages, exceptions?

Comment: I see a great big security hole here. Supposing `filename` was supplied as something like `"..\..\..\websites\myDomain.com\web.config"`.

Comment: why do you allocate a 1MB array, then allocate a ~10k array each iteration?

Comment: No error, the download just stops.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use `Response.TransmitFile` (or the equivalent action-results in MVC)?

Comment: THe site is made pre mvc

Comment: If an exception were to occur mid-transfer, the exception handler would itself throw because the `content-type` will already have been transmitted and will, at that point, (IIRC) be locked.

Comment: @ClemenGronver `Response.TransmitFile` is pre-MVC

Comment: @spender yes, but then you wouldn't get *any* data

Comment: I think that response.transmitfile is not used as it would lock up the browser while downloading

Answer (score 0):

You may have hit the request timeout. Take a note, if file stops downloading after some predetermined amount of time, like 60 or 300 seconds. If that is the case, you can configure timeouts in web.config of your application.

Comment: No timeout, its random time from download was started